# Joining 2 tables based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables that contain a record with a item and a date that i have mentioned below :

```
Table 1:
A  |  B
1    1/1
2    1/1
1    1/7
2    1/21
1    1/10
2    1/30

Table 2: 

A  |  C
1    1/10
1    1/12
1    1/17
2    1/14
2    1/23
2    1/23
```

I want the min date from table 2 to be assigned to table 1 for the minimum date in table 1. I have given the output table below:

```
A  |  B  |  C
1    1/1   1/10
1    1/7   1/12
1    1/10  1/17 
2    1/1   1/14
2    1/21  1/23 
2    1/30  1/23
```

Now, the min date from table 1 is associated to the min date in table 2 for a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumerate the values and join on that:

```
select t1.a, t1.b, t2.c
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t2.a = t1.a and t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum
```